# AngularJS How to JSON data read to Slim Framework (PUT method)

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

Welcome i have some JSON data and i want update this in database(I want to use Silm framework but I don't know how).
How can I send JSON data to PHP because this:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'Slim/Slim.php'
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->put('/saveUser/:idUser', function($idUser) {
  $user = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
  echo $user->newName.'  - '.$user->newEmail;
});
```

retrun me error

> 500 (Internal Server Error) Trying to get property of non-object

**app.js**:

```
var data = {
           idUser: 1,
           newName: 'Kaker',
           newEmail: 'aa@dd.com'
           }

 $http.put("app/api/saveUser/" + data.idUser, data);
```

Comment: Checking your browser dev tools, is the Angular PUT request sent to the corresponding URI? Specifically, does the "app/api/saveUser/:idUser" map correctly to your (I assume) "Slim/Slim.php/saveUser/:idUser"?

Comment: I checked angular map correctly URI

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->put('/saveUser/:idUser', function($idUser) use ($app) {
  $user = $app->request->put();

  echo $user->newName.'  - '.$user->newEmail;
});
```

Try this out :) you can find slim support on IRC, and we have our own forums as well.

Our docs are pretty awesome too 
http://www.slimframework.com/

Don't be afraid to open issues on our GitHub! 
https://github.com/slimphp/Slim